# Load objects from web service and show message if empty in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app I load objects from a web service and show them as a ion-list in my app. If there are no objects I want to show a message.

The http request works already.

So what I did:

```
export class RidePage {

  rides: Array<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.rides = this.loadRides(THIS GETS DATA FROM THE PROVIDER);
  }
```

In my template I have:

```
<p *ngIf="rides.length == 0">No conent</p>
```

But this return an error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rides` is undefined while the HTTP request is populating it. set it to empty or use the safe operator `rides?.length`

```
<p *ngIf="rides?.length == 0">No conent</p>
```

or

```
export class RidePage {

  rides: Array<any> = [];

  constructor() {
    this.rides = this.loadRides(THIS GETS DATA FROM THE PROVIDER);
  }
```

**EDIT**

If you want to display that text when no content is available just check if rides is empty otherwise the ngIf evaluates to false and you wont see text.

```
<p *ngIf="rides">No conent</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the result from an asynchronous call, You need to check if rides exists and check the length,

```
<p *ngIf="rides && rides.length == 0">No conent</p>
```

or you could just use safe navigation operator here

```
<p *ngIf="rides?.length == 0">No conent</p>
```

Comment: I thought rides exists always since I declare it in the beginning.

Comment: @almo it exists but is not defined